# Couldn't find [model] with 'id' = 4607

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to destroy a record, it gives me the error message "Couldn't find Checkout51 with 'id'=4906"

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'homepage#index'
    resources :savingstar
end
```

Savingstar Controller Method

```
def destroy
    Checkout51.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to "https://rails-tutorial2-chriscma.c9users.io/savingstar/show"
end
```

Link to trigger destroy method

```
    <p> <%= link_to 'Destroy', x, method: :delete %> </p>
```

Trace

```
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
app/controllers/savingstar_controller.rb:55:in `destroy'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.11) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'

Result of Checkout.find(4607) in Rails c


SELECT  "checkout51s".* FROM "checkout51s" WHERE "checkout51s"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4607]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Checkout51 with 'id'=4607
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
```

Comment: You cannot delete a resource that doesn't exist.

Comment: On my show page where I list the 'products', I put product.id and it does give me an id of 4607.

Comment: Please put the logs

Comment: Added. Ty for reminding me.

Comment: Run the rails console (`rails c`), and type `Checkout51.find(4607)`. What you see?

Comment: Another fact: in title you have ID `4607`, and in the error ID is `4906`. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: Oh no the ID is the same I just mistyped that.  I'm adding the result of what I got above.  Appreciate your time.